# designing websites for smartphones / mobiles

Tags: mobile, web

What is the best way to design a website and integrate web design for mobile devices within that website?

I heard the best solution is to simply create a separate CSS file...or redirect to another page that is designed for mobiles...

And are there any tools out there that make this task easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot depends on the complexity of the site. Many times your best option is to redirect to a mobile specific site. Frameworks like [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) can be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

- You can use responsive CSS media queries to make the same page look different on different device sizes.
- In case of standard CMSs like Wordpress/Drupal, there are plugins and themes which automate this for you.
- Or you can use a third-party service like MobStac for Developers or Mobify to create a mobile version of your site.

Responsive comes with its own set of limitations; for ex. the markup and content being served to all devices is the same. It does not result in a lighter or faster site by itself. You should look at [adaptive](http://venturebeat.com/2013/11/19/responsive-design-adaptive/) instead of plain responsive if you want an optimized experience across devices for your site visitors.